# Prove the inequality relation on natural number set.

Tags: inequality

Prove the following ineuality:
$$(2m+(m+n-1)(m+n-2))^2<16m^2.n^2 $$ for $m,n$ >=1, integers.

My try: I have used available identities and inequalities but can not reach the solution.

Comment: This inequality does not hold for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider for example $n=1$, then the left hand side reduces to $m^4 +2m^3+m^2$, while the right hand side is $16m^2$. Clearly, the desired inequality is not true for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Will it be true for all m,n >c, c a fixed natural number

Comment: You can just repeat my argument for that case. If $n=c+1$, then the left hand grows like $m^4$ for $m$ large enough, while the right hand side still is only quadratic in $m$. Plugging this inequality into wolfram alpha shows you when this inequality holds true. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282m%2B%28m%2Bn-1%29%28m%2Bn-2%29%29%5E2+%3C+16m%5E2n%5E2

Comment: Can you explain where you got this inequality from? Is there a possibility that you mis-wrote it?